# Paste Shortcut not working anywhere on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, browser, copy, paste

I have this weird issue every since installing Ubuntu. The shortcut for copy (Ctrl + C) works but the shortcut for paste (Ctrl + V) doesn't. This issue is across applications and browsers. However, copying with Ctrl + C and right-click paste works. How do I fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Where exactly are you trying to paste? If in terminal then CTRL+V doesn't work, it's CTRL+SHIFT+V (and CTRL+SHIFT+C, etc.)

Comment: It's not in the terminal, but everywhere, like I can copy using Ctrl + C from one tab and Ctrl + V will not work in the other tab.

Comment: I also have the same issue. Using LTS 20.04.4 and stable release Opera & Firefox. I occasionally get copy/paste working if copying short strings but not a whole paragraph.